# Weird mesh geometry on adding skin modifier.

Tags: modifiers

Merged all the vertices of a cube to get a single vertex and then extruded the vertices to create a structure. But after adding the skin modifier the mesh geometry is weird. The structure created with the vertices is on the left side and the one with skin modifier is on the right[image]

Comment: Try to look into mesh geometry to see if there aren't any double vertices or unconnected geometry. Simple way to do this in Edit mode is to select one vertex and press Ctrl+L, if everything is selected then all is correct. Then select all and W > Remove Doubles

Comment: What happens if you hit `Equalize Radii`? Scaling the thickness of every vertex down might help